# layout setting in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following structure:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:background="@drawable/framewhite"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        >

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBestPickTrivia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/testTrivia"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEntityName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Cars (2006)" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem arises at this line of ScrollView:

**android:layout_height="120dp"**

I want the height to be adjusted according to screen resolution, I've designed it by using **3.7in WVGA (Nexus One)** which works fine in my HTC Desire but when I've tested my app using HTC Explorer which uses **3.2 HVGA** it didn't work, the ScrollView crosses the screen boundary and I can't see my TextView i.e txtEntityName.

One more thing, is there any way I can dock any control as in .NET where the control can be docked to Top, bottom, right or left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/framewhite"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="right">

<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBestPickTrivia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/framewhite"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEntityName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Cars (2006)" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

it must works for all android screens size

Answer (score 0):

About the screen question, check http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

As for "docking", you can use `android:gravity` and/or absolute alignment properties (i.e. alignParentTop)

Answer (score 0):

You should use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and align your txtEntityName to the bottom and ScrollView to the top of parent and its bottom to the top of txtEntityName. Set layout_height of ScrollView to 0dp